# Azure authentication for ASP.net core API and React client

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, msal.js

I want to implement Microsoft Azure authentication for React client and Secured asp.net core API

only authenticated users can be able to access the methods from the react client

While hosting the application building the react sources and moving them to API wwwroot folder and hosting it as ASP.net core MVC application.

for the above requirement what is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

**yes you can use Azure Active Directory and you can acheive using graph API's refer the link below**

[Graph API's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/microsoft-graph-intro)

Comment: Any Sample example for the above requirement from my react client i should be able to call API for authentication with Azure Active Directory